# Dotnet Core Api string binding querystring params

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

In my api controller, I have a method:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("Confirm")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Confirm(string token) {
  //do stuff
}
```

If I send
/Confirm?token=test123 then token = "test123" (obviously)
/Confirm?token=test123+456 then token = "test123 456" (with a space for the + as expected)
/Confirm?token=test123%2B456 then token = "test123 456" (with a space)

`Request.Query["token"].ToString()` also results in a space
"test123 123"

The first two calls are expected, the third is not as the space is correctly encoded. It seems to be converted to a plus and the converted again to the space.

I have tried on IISEXPRESS and Kestrel servers from in visual studio and the same behaviour is observed.

Anyone have any ideas on the right combination of encoding to actually get the binding to bind correctly?

The scenario is the typical Identity provider tokens being generated, sent in email, and being confirmed.

Comment: There may be something you aren't seeing or observing correctly, because using `%2B` properly converts to a `+` sign for me using ASP.NET Core 3.1. Are you taking that string and putting it back in to a different URL? Because then it would convert to a space if you don't `URLEncode` it first. And a side note: The parameter should be `MethodName([FromQuery] string token){...}` if you expect it from the query.

Comment: You've pointed me in the right direction. thanks! I was still testing via the Nuxt.js app, when I use the dotnet core endpoint directly in the browser, it does work fine. I'll check what Nuxt is doing with the values.

Comment: Yea, it was exactly NUXT decoding the link, I need to re-encode again when passing back to the backend api call. (Was obviously getting too late last night) Thanks again